# Gradient + Image Background whitout overlapping

Tags: html, css, background

I´m trying to set a brackground with the following structure: a gradient until the middle of the page and after a certain height the gradient should stop existing and a normal image should appear on the background.

I already tried to adapt every solution I found about 2 images background or gradient background(position, origin, repeat, width, height,etc), but the gradient entirely overlaps  the image in every solution I´ve tried.

Where can I found some material or tutorial to be able to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example to accomplish what you're looking to do (as I understand it).

The background image covers an entire container. Then, the container is split into two equal halves where only the bottom half gets the gradient.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
     .main {
        height: 800px;
        width: 800px;
        background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552058544-f2b08422138a?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=644&q=80');
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
      }
      .top {
        height: 50%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .gradient{
        height: 50%;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, red 50%, transparent); 
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="top"></div>
      <div class="gradient"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like below:

```css
body {
  min-height:300vh;
  background:
    linear-gradient(blue,red,transparent) top/100% 50vh no-repeat,
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/1014/500/1000) center/cover;
}
```